# Put on/keep on/use on

Tags: grammar, word-usage

[image: Hot Water Bottle]

So if we want warmth,we use a.hot water bottle (sometimes)
So what should it be :

Put hot water bottle on your feet.

Use hot water bottle on your feet.

Keep hot water bottle on your feet.

What should be used "put on/use on/keep on"?
Thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three are grammatically correct, but have different meanings.

**put ... on** means that you don't have a hot water bottle on your feet and suggests that you should place a hot water bottle on your feet.

**use ... on** does not specify any start or end.

**keep ... on** means that there is already a hot water bottle on your feet, and if you want your feet to stay warm, you'd better leave it there.

**put ... on** is probably the one that you need, for example...

> If your feet are cold, put a hot water bottle on them.

---

Note that an indefinite article **a** is required in all of the example sentences in your question.